# Проект перестал запускаться на localhost

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, localhost, dhcp

Доброго дня. Написал простенький веб-апи сервер на asp.net core котрый успешно запускался на локалхосте (винда 10). Потом по необходимости нужно было настроить удаленный доступ к компу (в настройках роутера - установил постоянный адрес DHCP клиента) После чего (мне почему-то кажется что проблема в этом) проект перестал запускаться на локальном хосте. По умолчанию проект запускается на 50292 порту и выдает 404 -ю ошибку. Однако в окне вывода VS2017 пишет что прослушивание начато на другом порту. Пытался достучаться через этот порт, но в окне вывода выдает следующее:

`'MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN' does not match the expected pairing token '4ed0e865-dfc4-4e75-8ad1-3569ab45ae66', request rejected.`

Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой и поможет дельным советом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поблема разрешилась сама собой. Пришло обновление в студию установил и теперь все запускается, в общем какойто левый глюк.